# ajax calendar control not reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax calendar control used in my form for to date and from date.

The issue with it is, if I select date from previous year and click on reset button, the textbox containing date gets cleared but now when focus is set on the textbox the calendar control shows month of the year previously selected.

Is there any way we can reset calendar control as well on click of the reset button?

```
function Reset(divs) {
    $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove();
    ClearErrorMsg();
    $('#' + divs + ' input[type="text"]').val('');
    $('#' + divs + ' select').val('');
    $('#' + divs + ' input[type="text"]').attr({ "value": "" });

    var BrwsrType = BrowserType();

    if (BrwsrType == 'IE') {
        $('#' + divs + ' select option').each(function () {
           $("select option").removeAttr('selected');
       })
   };

   $("select").each(function (i) {
       $('select :nth-child(1)').attr('selected', 'selected')
       $('select')[i].options[0].selected = true
   });

    var txtpagesize = $get('txtPageSize');
    if (txtpagesize != null) {
        txtpagesize.value = txtpagesize.attributes["defValue"].value;
        $('#' + txtpagesize.id).attr({ "value": txtpagesize.attributes["defValue"].value });
    }

    HideDialog();
    try {
        Page_ClientValidate('');
    }
    catch (er) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the function which is called on reset button is as follows

```
  function ResetForm() {
            Reset('Search');
            $(".dropdown").each(function () {
                $('.dropdown :nth-child(1)').attr('selected', 'selected')
            });



            isValidDate($get('txtBeginDate'));
            isValidDate($get('txtEndDate'));
            HideCallOut();

            $get('txtBeginDate').defaultValue = "";
            $get('txtEndDate').defaultValue = "";
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: can you please some of your code??

Comment: just set calendarextendarid.defaultvalue= "";

Comment: wat u have tried regarding that? post that too..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   function resetcalendar()
    {

 $find("_Calendar").set_selectedDate(null);
        $("[id*=Calendar]").val("");
        $(".ajax__calendar_active").removeClass("ajax__calendar_active");
        return false;
   }
</script>
```

where _Calendar is the BehaviorID of Calendarextender and Calendar is the ID of Calendarextender

Hope this helps

Happy Coding

Comment: I used this as it is  and it worked, but when instead of "_Calendar" i used my calendar control's behavior id and instead of "[id*=Calendar]" I used my control's ID, it does not work. Can you tell me what can be the reason for this

Comment: @user3118378 what is the problem?

Comment: Also while debugging, the ie debugger gives error of cannot set selectedDate to null ref

Comment: can you tell me whether i need to use the script provided as it is or change the behavior id and id in it ?

Comment: please double check it i have tested it and it worked fine for me you are doing mistake in behaviorid i guess

Comment: yes it works fine with the above script, but my doubt is do I need to change the behavior id and id given in the script with my calendar control's behavior id and id?

Comment: No you can use your own id no problem will arise, if it helped please mark it answer so it will be useful for someone in the future. thanks

Comment: use _along with your behaviorid